# Changing a form object's property from a separate class

Tags: c#, forms, class, object

I'm very new to using C#. If you have ever heard of the Karol the robot program that is written in Java then that's what I'm aiming to build.

But I am stumbling at almost the first hurdle, I want to make a class for Karol (It is just a picture) that can move around the screen in blocks of 32x32 squares.

Trouble is when you create a class you can't access the properties of form objects because they are separate things.

I would like to be able to manipulate form objects from my class but without having to pass the object through the method each time I use it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not need to pass a reference of the `Form` *every* time. Should be enough to do something like this:

```
`public class Karol 

  {

private Form _form=null;

public Karol(Form frm) {

      _form = frm;
}

// after use _form inside the functions and     properties of the class, where needed

 }`
```

**edit**

to acces a control data inside a `Form` it needs to expose or controls itself, like

`public Label MyFormLabel {....}`

Or expose a functions/properties that sets or gets the data from the control.

`public string MyFormLabelText { get{ return label.Text;} set{label.Text = value;}}`

Comment: Thanks for idea. Can't get it to work though. When I instansiate the form in Main() I am using Karol Karol = new Karol(this); And in the Karol class I have done what you said, but when I do _Form. it won't let me do _Form.'form object'

Comment: @Zephni: if you pass `this` being in `MainForm` , it's already ok. Inside your class you save a reference to that form and use it. Where is the problem?

Comment: I pass 'this' to class when I create it, and then in the constuctor I have Form1 form1 = form1; But after that I can't use form1.label1 or form1.KarolObject ... Am I doing it all wrong, or just expecting it to be easier than it is? Sorry for my incompetance

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one form object that "Karol" is manipulating, you should be able to pass it to the constructor and save it for use in later member calls. That way you only pass it once at construction time.

Comment: I can get your solution to work, thanks :) I wish I could get Tigrans to work just coz' I want to understand it. But thanks :)